# ¿Cómo listar todos los modulos que PHP usa en el servidor que corre?

Tags: php

Estoy obteniendo la información del entorno de desarrollo en el que trabajo, que es debian con apache 2, postgresql 9.5, y php 5.6.30, sin embargo no recuerdo todas las extensiones o modulos que instalé para poder desarrollar el sistema.

Se que podría usar `phpinfo()` pero es un poco tedioso ya que muestra demasiada información.

**¿Existe algun comando para obtener la información de los modulos instalados para PHP?**

Answer (score 4):

En la consola se podría usar

```
php -m
```

que mostrará todos los módulos instalados, de la siguiente forma:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

También se puede usar:

```
php -i
```

que dará información más detallada de la configuración actual.

Answer (score 1):

En consola puedes usar `php -m`

Si lo que necesitas es obtener esta información dentro de un script, puedes usar [get_loaded_extensions()](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) que te devolverá un array con los nombres de las extensiones o módulos cargados actualmente:

```
<?php
    print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

Podría devolver algo como:

```
Array
(
   [0] => xml
   [1] => wddx
   [2] => standard
   [3] => session
   [4] => posix
   [5] => pgsql
   [6] => pcre
   [7] => gd
   [8] => ftp
   [9] => db
   [10] => calendar
   [11] => bcmath
)
```